# How can I send back response headers with Node.js / Express?

Tags: node.js, express, response-headers

I'm using `res.send` and no matter what, it returns status of 200. I want to set that status to different numbers for different responses (Error, etc)

This is using `express`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream'});
```

http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.12/api/http.html#response.writeHead

Answer (score 59):

For adding response headers *before* send, you can use the **setHeader** method:

```
response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
```

The status *only* by the **status** method:

```
response.status(status_code)
```

*Both* at the same time with the **writeHead** method:

```
response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
```

Answer (score 15):

I'll assume that you're using a library like "Express", since nodejs doesn't provide a`res.send` method.

As in the [Express guide](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#res.send%28%29), you can pass in a second optional argument to send the response status, such as:

```
// Express 3.x
res.send( "Not found", 404 );

// Express 4.x
res.status(404).send("Not found");
```

Comment: Note that now the parameters are in the reverse order:
`res.send(404, "Not found");`
The old way still works, but I would change it to keep up with the times.

Comment: Beyond the ordering problem mentioned by Martin Adoue, This answer isn't really true anymore, if it ever was.  Using res.send() sets the payload, not the status message.

Comment: Now this one is deprecated, even if you use in reverse order. Although it would work you should use: `res.status(404).send("Not Found");

Answer (score 9):

Since the question also mentions Express you could also do it this way using middleware.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream');
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 7):

You should use **setHeader** method and **status** method for your purpose.

**SOLUTION:**

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res) {

  // ...Check login credentials with DB here...

  if(!err) {
    var data = {
      success: true,
      message: "Login success"
    };

    // Adds header
    res.setHeader('custom_header_name', 'abcde');

    // responds with status code 200 and data
    res.status(200).json(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: This is definitely Express code, and not plain Node.js

Comment: @ZachSmith The OP asked for NodeJS/Express. So what's the issue? Just to let you know, if it's just my answer's title, you could have edited it.

Comment: Sorry yes - it was just the title and I could have edited it. Apologies

Answer (score 4):

set **statusCode** var before send() call

```
res.statusCode = 404;
res.send();
```

Answer (score 4):

In the documentation of [express](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.sendStatus) (4.x) the res.sendStatus is used to send status code definitions. As it is mentioned [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) each has a specific description.

```
res.sendStatus(200); // equivalent to res.status(200).send('OK')
res.sendStatus(403); // equivalent to res.status(403).send('Forbidden')
res.sendStatus(404); // equivalent to res.status(404).send('Not Found')
res.sendStatus(500); // equivalent to res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error')
```

Answer (score 3):

i use this with express

```
res.status(status_code).send(response_body);
```

and this without express (normal http server)

```
res.writeHead(404, {
    "Content-Type": "text/plain"
});
res.write("404 Not Found\n");
res.end();
```